# How to debug ajax in laravel 4

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, laravel, laravel-4

I want to know how to debug ajax in Laravel 4, because when error, I only get and error 500.

I'm making ajax request with jQuery.

Comment: If you want to see the request you can use Firebug, a browser extension. But you can also check your app's log files about the 500 error.

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools, no extension or logs are needed.  See below for easiest answer in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Laravel Log to debug it in Laravel:

```
Log::info('Whatever you need to send to your log');
```

And check your log for your messages and all error messages:

```
php artisan tail
```

Answer (score 6):

Another easier answer is:

In Chrome,

1. go to Network menu
2. Click the path/error
3. Go to Preview tab

The full error message is visible there.

[Laravel 4.2 and AJAX POST - 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229608/laravel-4-2-and-ajax-post-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: what a life saver:))

Answer (score 0):

Another way, and, to have more specificity of the error (like 500 Internal Server Error),  surround your code into a try/catch block and send the error/exception message as a JSON object for instance.

```
$.post('http://localhost/post_request,
    {
        '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        'input_xxx': 'value'
    })
      .fail(function(data) {
        data.error / data.debug
      })
      .success(function(data) {

    });
```

--------------***---------------

```
    try{

        //post request action(s) handling here


    }catch(Exception $e){
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.',
                'debug'=> $e->getMessage()
            ]);
    }
```